# Get auto incremented div id so that it can be used with ajax to return a value back to php

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using mysql_query results to create an html form like below with auto incremented prefixed value for div ids:

```
<div id="favorite'.$count.'">
  <form action="javascript:void(0);" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="sec" value="'.$ident_inpt.'"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="t" id="t'.$count.'" value="mo-'.$usr.'-'.$rmid.'-'.$_SESSION['STORE'].'"/>
    <input type="submit" value="'.$lang['590'].'" class="favorites" onclick="upd_favorite();"/>
  </form>
</div>
```

How can I get the ids of favorite### and t###  so that I can get the loop going?

I use this but only works with static ids:

`$('#favorite').html(ajaxRequest.responseText);`

and:   `var addit = document.getElementById("t").value;`

Thanks in advance for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also specify a common class across the elements:

```
<div id="favorite1" class="favs"></div>
<div id="favorite2" class="favs"></div>
```

And then you can grab them all like:

```
$('.favs').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).id);
}
```

You could also specify a custom attribute like:

```
<div id="favorite1" customattr="favorite"></div>
```

And grab them like:

```
$('[customattr=favorite]').each(function() { ... };
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like the following. demo: http://jsfiddle.net/MCkRk/

```
$('div[id^=favorite]').each(function() {
  console.log('inputval', $(this).find('input[id^=t]').val());
});​
```